# ExecuteQuery returns 1 but does not delete the entry

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am using JDBC and I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I want to delete a user. Here is my code:

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
        // delete user
        String deleteUser_sql = "Delete from \"User\" "
                + "where email = ?";
        PreparedStatement deleteUser_statement = con.
                prepareStatement(deleteUser_sql);
        deleteUser_statement.setString(1, "user@email.com");
        int res2 = deleteUser_statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception myMethod"  + e);
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, I can see that the `res2 = 1`.

However, when I open the terminal, connect to the `psql -d mydatabase`, and execute the following sql:
`select * from "User" where email = "user@email.com"`, I can see the user still exists.

What is happening?

Comment: Did you set auto commit to false? Then you are missing a `commit()`

Comment: Ah, again you :). 
I was writing a test case for my function. I did not use `autoCommit(false)` in the test, but I have `AutoCommit(false)` in the real application.

In the real application, I am committing statements when I'm done with them.